# Protocol Error when writing to vbox shared folder

Tags: linux, virtualbox, shared-folders, centos-6

So to begin I am running a server where a vbox vm is running that has a shared folder mounted to transfer items in and out of the vm. This shared folder goes to multiple vms on the server. Recently this shared folder is no longer able to be written to. I can read it and cp from the sf to the vm; but cannot write vm to sf:

VM is running centos 6.

```
[root@Necalli Test]# cp -rf /home/dashman/_* ./
cp: cannot create directory `./_Definitions': Protocol error
cp: cannot create directory `./_SupportFiles': Protocol error
cp: cannot create directory `./_Themes': Protocol error
```

This setup used to work for me and I am unsure when it stopped working. possibly after a reboot but unknown for sure. Would anyone have any help for me? If so could you provide details on the steps to alleviate, much appreciated.

I have tried writing as root and check /etc/group vboxsf for user added to group.

When outside the vm the shared folder is:

```
drwxr-xr-x   15 root   root     4096 Oct  7 16:04 GoldenData
```

Inside the vm:

```
drwxrwx---.  1 root    vboxsf  4096 Oct  7 16:04 sf_GoldenData
```